# How to Include Gem for Third Party Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, rvm, require

I am using RVM to install versions of Ruby that work with me (`rich`) the user.  I'm also using another application that calls Ruby scripts as a different user, not `rich`.  This means the Ruby shebang needs to follow the RVM lead to the default Ruby version I have chosen.

`#!/Users/rich/.rvm/rubies/default/bin/ruby`

Testing for `RUBY_VERSION` indicates as much.  So far so good.  However I am relying on the `clipboard` gem, which does not show up, because of how RVM works.  RVM doesn't apply the gemset which works for me as a user.

How can I get the gemset to be recognized/loaded for this other user?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  Use this shebang:

`#!/Users/rich/.rvm/wrappers/default/ruby`